# flask restful: passing parameters to GET request

Tags: python, rest, flask, flask-restful

I want to create a resource that supports GET request in following way:

```
/bar?key1=val1&key2=val2
```

I tried this code, but it is not working

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class BarAPI(Resource):
    def get(key1, key2):
        return jsonify(dict(data=[key1, key2]))

api.add_resource(BarAPI, '/bar', endpoint='bar')
```

Thanks!

Comment: a little while has passed since you asked your question and the answer you selected uses an API that is deprecated. Could you update the accepted answer?

Comment: indeed, there is a better library called flask_restful in which you can define resources ('hooks' to your database that define CRUD operations), add them to an API, and bind that API to Flask using Blueprints. In it you will find the RequestParser class for parsing arguments passed as a document body.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Flask can parse arguments through request

```
from flask import request
```

You can use following lines in the block that requires GET parameters. GET is declared in `@app.route()` declaration.

```
args = request.args
print (args) # For debugging
no1 = args['key1']
no2 = args['key2']
return jsonify(dict(data=[no1, no2])) # or whatever is required
```

Comment: While Flask request object make it easy to retrieve GET parameters, it's not doing any of the data validation. The better way is use a Object Data Mapper like `marshmallow` or `webargs`(created by the same author of marshmallow) to do data validation and filtering to ensure AppSec

Comment: `request.args.get('key1', DEFAULT_COUNT, type=int)` a better way handle in case when query not passing.

Answer (score 61):

**Edit: `reqparse` is no longer the recommended way to do this with flask-restful!**, but there is another example using marshmallow below.

The `reqparse` object is deprecated. See the [docs](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reqparse.html) or the second example in this post for alternatives.

---

Use `reqparse`. You can see another example in the flask-restful [docs](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#argument-parsing).

It performs validation on the parameters and does not require `jsonify`.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class BarAPI(Resource):
    def get(self):

        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('key1', type=str)
        parser.add_argument('key2', type=str)

        return parser.parse_args()

api.add_resource(BarAPI, '/bar', endpoint='bar')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

Another way is to use [marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io).

You can use a `Schema` class,to validate `request.args` (for a PUT/POST request you might validate `request.form`)

```
from flask import Flask, request, abort
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from marshmallow import Schema, fields


class BarQuerySchema(Schema):
    key1 = fields.Str(required=True)
    key2 = fields.Str(required=True)

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
schema = BarQuerySchema()


class BarAPI(Resource):
    def get(self):
        errors = schema.validate(request.args)
        if errors:
            abort(400, str(errors))

        return 'ok'

api.add_resource(BarAPI, '/bar', endpoint='bar')

# omit of you intend to use `flask run` command
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This example requires that both parameters be present.

Answer (score 39):

Since `reqparse` is deprecated, here is a solution using the [WebArgs](https://github.com/sloria/webargs) library:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, abort
from webargs import fields, validate
from webargs.flaskparser import use_kwargs, parser

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Foo(Resource):
    args = {
        'bar': fields.Str(
            required=True,
            validate=validate.OneOf(['baz', 'qux']),
        ),
    }

    @use_kwargs(args)
    def get(self, bar):
        return {'bar': bar}

api.add_resource(Foo, '/foo', endpoint='foo')

# This error handler is necessary for usage with Flask-RESTful.
@parser.error_handler
def handle_request_parsing_error(err, req, schema, *, error_status_code, error_headers):
    abort(error_status_code, errors=err.messages)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

For more examples, see the [Flask-RESTful example](https://github.com/sloria/webargs/blob/dev/examples/flaskrestful_example.py) in the WebArgs repository.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @severen is from 2016 and a bit outdated with regards to webargs. As i understand it, with the major update to 6.0.0 (in 2020), the decorator looks at the json payload by default and disregards the parameters within the query. To add this hint, add `location="query"` to the decorator (see [github issue](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/webargs/issues/483#issuecomment-592798051) ).

Taking the example above, a working Endpoint which accepts a GET request would look like this:

```
class Foo(Resource):
    @use_kwargs({"bar": fields.Str(), }, location="query")
    def get(self, bar):
        return {'message': 'Hello, ' + bar}, 200
```