# Passing HTTP parameters from request url with Flask

Tags: python, rest, flask, http-parameters

Below is the code I'm using for Simple REST API. It is working fine.
The REST URL is like http://127.0.0.1:8080/sample/100
But I need to pass 100 as a key value pair like http://127.0.0.1:8080/sample?runtime=100. Is this possible or any other python library that will help

```
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Analysis(Resource):
def get(self, runtime):
   result2 = result1.to_json(orient='records')
   return json.loads(result2)

api.add_resource(Analysis, '/sample/<runtime>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(port='8080')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30779584/flask-restful-passing-parameters-to-get-request

Comment: I have tried the above one. It's not working for me :(

Comment: If you tried the linked solution, then please provide the code where you do so and describe the exact error you did observe.

Answer (score 0):

Check out "The Request Object" section of the Flask Quickstart documentation here: 
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/

> To access parameters submitted in the URL (?key=value) you can use the args attribute:

```
searchword = request.args.get('key', '')
```

make sure you include this in your imports:

```
from flask import request
```