# Unable to parse arguments in Flask Restful for GET request

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

With reference to the below code, I am getting an error while parsing the parameters for a `GET` request in Flask Restful.

```py
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse

class View_Result(Resource):

    def get(self):

        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('aid', type=str)
        print('Here 1')
        data = parser.parse_args()
        print('Here 2')
```

URL: http://127.0.0.1:8502/view_result?aid=1

Console:

```bash
Here 1
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Nov/2022 01:52:43] "GET /view_result?aid=1 HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

Webpage:

```json
{
    "message": "Did not attempt to load JSON data because the request Content-Type was not 'application/json'."
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you've defined a `get` method, but `reqparse` is designed to work with a JSON request body in a `POST` (or `PUT`) request. You would need:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class View_Result(Resource):

    def post(self):

        parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        parser.add_argument('aid', type=str)
        print('Here 1')
        data = parser.parse_args()
        print('Here 2', data)

api.add_resource(View_Result, '/')
```

If I place the above code in `resultful.py` and then run it:

```
flask --debug --app restful run
```

I can make the following request:

```
curl localhost:5000 -H 'content-type: application/json' -d '{"aid": "foo"}'
```

And see on the application console:

```
Here 1
Here 2 {'aid': 'foo'}
127.0.0.1 - - [08/Nov/2022 17:23:08] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: I would like to have a `GET` request instead. But to my knowledge, I have already used `reqparse` with `GET` requests in some applications and it works fine. Any thoughts?

Comment: A GET request can't have a body, so `reqparse` seems like the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I just came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30779996/11608962) which mentions that `reqparse` is deprecated. Used `request.args` to get these arguments.